# forever does not start node server - V8 options passed to the command are not recognized

Tags: node.js, v8, forever

I am using the following command to start a node server using forever.

```
forever start -c "node --harmony_proxies" server.js
```

But the server does not start. Throws the following error and terminates.

```
throw new Error("proxies not supported on this platform. On v8/node/iojs, make sure to pass the --harmony_proxies flag");
  ^
```

> Error: proxies not supported on this platform. On v8/node/iojs, make sure to pass the --harmony_proxies flag

Looks like the way I am passing the node options is wrong.

Hoping to get suggestions to resolve this issue.

Comment: Proxy is supported in Node.js 6.0 and higher. Is it possible for you to upgrade?

Comment: what version of node are you using?